# Getting wrong answer when trying to output a an actors roles

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, select

I am trying to figure out how I can get `Daniel Radcliffe`'s career history. However, I am getting results which aren't relevant to `Daniel Radcliffe`.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null
);

CREATE TABLE movie (
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null
);

CREATE TABLE casts (
  movie_id integer not null,
  person_id integer not null,
  played_as text not null,
  foreign key (movie_id) references movie(id),
  foreign key (person_id) references person(id)
);

CREATE TABLE crew (
  movie_id integer not null,
  person_id integer not null,
  job text not null,
  foreign key (movie_id) references movie(id),
  foreign key (person_id) references person(id)
);

CREATE TABLE famous_level (
  movie_id integer not null,
  person_id integer not null,
  level integer not null,
  foreign key (movie_id) references movie(id),
  foreign key (person_id) references person(id)
);

INSERT INTO person (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Daniel Radcliffe'), (2, 'Emma Watson'), (3, 'Robert Downey Jr.'), (4, 'Joss Whedon');
INSERT INTO movie (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Harry Potter movie'), (2, 'The Avengers');
INSERT INTO casts (movie_id, person_id, played_as) VALUES (1, 1, 'Harry Potter'), (1, 2, 'Hermione Granger'), (2, 3, 'Tony Stark');
INSERT INTO crew (movie_id, person_id, job) VALUES (1, 1, 'Writer'), (1, 4, 'Director'), (2, 2, 'Director'), (2, 1, 'Writer');
INSERT INTO famous_level (movie_id, person_id, level) VALUES (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 2), (1, 4, 2);
```

---

I know the that `Daniel Radcliffe`'s ID is `1`

```
SELECT
  m.name,
  ct.played_as,
  cr.job
FROM movie m
JOIN crew cr ON m.id = cr.movie_id
JOIN casts ct ON m.id = ct.movie_id
JOIN famous_level f ON m.id = f.movie_id
JOIN person p ON cr.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1
ORDER BY f.level ASC
```

I want to get the result as something similar to this, where there are NULL values on either the played_as or job column

```
+--------------------+--------------+--------+
|        name        |  played_as   |  job   |
+--------------------+--------------+--------+
| Harry Potter movie | Harry Potter | NULL   |
| Harry Potter movie | NULL         | Writer |
| The Avengers       | NULL         | Writer |
+--------------------+--------------+--------+
```

Result I get: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/28dd0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to get one row for each `played_as` or `job` for each movie, you need to create a table with all the `played_as` and `job` values, which you can do with a `UNION` query. That query returns `NULL` for `job` when `played_as` is valid and vice versa. It can then be `JOIN`ed to the `movie`, `person` and `famous_level` tables to filter on the `person_id` and order by the `level`:

```
SELECT m.name,
       r.played_as,
       r.job
FROM movie m
JOIN (
  SELECT movie_id, person_id, played_as, NULL as job
  FROM casts
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT movie_id, person_id, NULL, job
  FROM crew
) r ON r.movie_id = m.id
JOIN person p ON p.id = r.person_id
LEFT JOIN famous_level f ON f.movie_id = m.id AND f.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1
ORDER BY COALESCE(f.level, 99)
```

Output:

```
name                played_as       job
Harry Potter movie  (null)          Director
Harry Potter movie  (null)          Writer
Harry Potter movie  Harry Potter    (null)
The Avengers        (null)          Writer
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8782a/10)

Note that you need to `JOIN` to `famous_level` on both `movie_id` and `person_id` to avoid getting extra rows in the output. Since not all movie/person combinations have a `famous_level`, you need to use a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` on the `level` value for when it is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, My question is what if I insert this into the table `INSERT INTO crew (movie_id, person_id, job) VALUES (1, 1, 'Director')`. How can I see Daniel's full career now. Also I do need the famous_level as I use it for `ORDER BY level ASC`

Comment: how can I make played_as be null if job exists?

Comment: Do you want to get one row per `played_as` or `job` for each movie (as you show in your output, but not what my query currently produces)?

Comment: Yes, I want to get one row per played_as or job for each movie

Comment: @Paul please see my edit. I think that addresses your issues.

Comment: Just one more question, how can I make it so if they don't have an entry in the `famous_levels` table, they I shouldn't show that movie in the results table at all?

Comment: Just change the `LEFT JOIN famous_level` to `JOIN famous_level`. In that scenario you can remove the `COALESCE` in the `ORDER BY` clause too.